# DiskPart status list

Tags: command-line, diskpart

I'm writing a simple script that checks the output from `diskpart` for certain keywords. I am running `echo list volume|diskpart` and then checking the output for failed or whatever bad status is listed.

Whare are the different options other than health that a drive could have?

Comment: go through [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but unfortunately it doesn't contain the information I require.  I have looked through as many of those microsoft documentation sites as I can find with no luck.

"Displays a list of basic and dynamic volumes on all disks."

Is all that is listed under the list volume command, and no where does it have a possible volume status list.  I know healthy is the normal state, but some places mention failed, failed rd, or missing.  What Im looking for is a comprehensive list of states.

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of the following status/info codes listed by `diskpart` under Windows 7 (US-English) when selecting to list volumes (`echo list volume|diskpart`):

**"Status" Column Codes:** `Failed Rd` `Healthy` `No Media` `Rebuild` `Unusable`

**"Info" Column Codes:** `At Risk` `System` `Boot` `Pagefile` `Hidden`

With regards to your question on searching for failed Drives/RAIDs I would recommend searching for strings: `Fail` `Risk` `Rebuild`